# Reset Bios Admin Password on Lenovo

Tags: bios, passwords, administrator, reset

I have a Lenovo Legion 7 laptop and I recently forgot the Bios admin password, I only know the user one. I'm not able to change the Bios settings anymore so I need help to reset this password or the Bios, which I updated it to the latest version 10, from the lenovo support website. Can't remember my old password, a recent surgery messed up my mind.

Comment: It has to be sent to Lenovo for a reset, there are not tools available to do it yourself.

Comment: That is so annoying it has to be a way or a procedure Lenovo has for this cases.

Comment: There is, send it to an authorized lenovo repair facility.